# I don't get prices with Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I try to get prices of an ASIN number with the Amazon Product Advertising API.

Code:

```
    $artNr = "B003TKSD8E";
    $base_url = "http://ecs.amazonaws.de/onca/xml";
    $params = array(
        'AWSAccessKeyId' => self::API_KEY,
        'AssociateTag' => self::API_ASSOCIATE_TAG,
        'Version' => "2010-11-01",
        'Operation' => "ItemLookup",
        'Service' => "AWSECommerceService",
        'Condition' => "All",
        'IdType' => 'ASIN',
        'ItemId' => $artNr);

        
    $params['Timestamp'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
     
    $url_parts = array();
    foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
        $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));
    sort($url_parts);
     
    $url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
    $string_to_sign = "GET\necs.amazonaws.de\n/onca/xml\n" . $url_string;

    $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, self::API_SECRET, TRUE);
    
    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));
     
    $url = $base_url . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;
        
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $parsed_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

I think this should be correct - but I don't get offers in the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01">
    <OperationRequest>
      <RequestId>*********************</RequestId>
      <Arguments>
        <Argument Name="Condition" Value="All">
      </Argument>
        <Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemLookup">
      </Argument>
        <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService">
      </Argument>
        <Argument Name="ItemId" Value="B003TKSD8E">
      </Argument>
        <Argument Name="IdType" Value="ASIN">
      </Argument>
        <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="*********************">
      </Argument>
        <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2011-11-29T01:49:01.000Z">
      </Argument>
        <Argument Name="Signature" Value="*********************">
      </Argument>
        <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="*********************">
      </Argument>
        <Argument Name="Version" Value="2010-11-01">
      </Argument>
    </Arguments>
      <RequestProcessingTime>0.0083130000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
    </OperationRequest>
    <Items>
      <Request>
        <IsValid>True</IsValid>
        <ItemLookupRequest>
          <Condition>All</Condition>
          <IdType>ASIN</IdType>
          <ItemId>B003TKSD8E</ItemId>
          <ResponseGroup>Small</ResponseGroup>
          <VariationPage>All</VariationPage>
        </ItemLookupRequest>
      </Request>
      <Item>
        <ASIN>B003TKSD8E</ASIN>
        <DetailPageURL>http://www.amazon.de/Apple-iPhone-4-32GB-schwarz/dp/B003TKSD8E%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6NFQHK2DQIPRUEQ%26tag%3Dbanholzerme-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB003TKSD8E</DetailPageURL>
        <ItemLinks>
          <ItemLink>
            <Description>Add To Wishlist</Description>
            <URL>http://www.amazon.de/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB003TKSD8E%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6NFQHK2DQIPRUEQ%26tag%3Dbanholzerme-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D12738%26creativeASIN%3DB003TKSD8E</URL>
          </ItemLink>
          <ItemLink>
            <Description>Tell A Friend</Description>
            <URL>http://www.amazon.de/gp/pdp/taf/B003TKSD8E%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6NFQHK2DQIPRUEQ%26tag%3Dbanholzerme-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D12738%26creativeASIN%3DB003TKSD8E</URL>
          </ItemLink>
          <ItemLink>
            <Description>All Customer Reviews</Description>
            <URL>http://www.amazon.de/review/product/B003TKSD8E%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6NFQHK2DQIPRUEQ%26tag%3Dbanholzerme-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D12738%26creativeASIN%3DB003TKSD8E</URL>
          </ItemLink>
          <ItemLink>
            <Description>All Offers</Description>
            <URL>http://www.amazon.de/gp/offer-listing/B003TKSD8E%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6NFQHK2DQIPRUEQ%26tag%3Dbanholzerme-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D12738%26creativeASIN%3DB003TKSD8E</URL>
          </ItemLink>
        </ItemLinks>
        <ItemAttributes>
          <Manufacturer>Apple Computer</Manufacturer>
          <ProductGroup>CE</ProductGroup>
          <Title>Apple iPhone 4 32GB schwarz</Title>/ItemAttributes>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </ItemLookupResponse>
```

Why don't I get any price-information?

Comment: fyi: it's ASIN - amazon standard identification number. ANSI is american national standards institute.

Comment: Try `echo $parsed_xml->asXML();` instead of `print_r` because `print_r` does not show the whole picture with `SimpleXML`.

Comment: @hakre I changed the response - the price wasn't hidden

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get prices for an item you need to include a `ResponseGroup` parameter of `Offers` or `OfferFull` and a `MerchantId` parameter of `All`:

```
$params = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => self::API_KEY,
    'AssociateTag' => self::API_ASSOCIATE_TAG,
    'Version' => "2010-11-01",
    'Operation' => "ItemLookup",
    'Service' => "AWSECommerceService",
    'Condition' => "All",
    'IdType' => 'ASIN',
    'ResponseGroup' => 'Offers',                <- important
    'MerchantId' => 'All',                      <- important
    'ItemId' => $artNr);
```

If you don't include the `MerchantId` of `All` you will only get offer listings for Amazon (the default `MerchantId`). This will return the **offer listings** and your response will include something like the following:

```
<Items>
    ...
    <Item>
        ...
        <Offers>
            ...
            <Offer>
                ...
                <OfferListing>
                    <Price>
                        <Amount>1350</Amount>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                        <FormattedPrice>$13.50</FormattedPrice>
                    </Price>
                    ...
                </OfferListing>
                ...
            </Offer>
       ...
```

See the documentation for the [Offers Response Group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Offers.html) for more information. Also see the Response Group request parameter description for the [ItemLookup operation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) for more valid Response Groups.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the solution!

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue and the ResponseGroup and MarchentId solution is not working for me. The differences are, 1) my version is "2011-08-01" 2) I'm using Java to implement it. Another issue I noticed is, even if I pass ResponseGroup=Medium, it shows <ResponseGroup>Small</ResponseGroup> in the response. Is there any other alternative for it?

Comment: @San No, I don't believe so. It's been a while since I've worked with this so I don't have any current info.

Comment: @JonathanSpooner, Yes it is working! the issue was some of the products returned from Amazon does not have price details.

Comment: The only valid option for MerchantId is "Amazon". So maybe they made "All" the default. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AvailabilityParamterConstraints.html

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the OfferSummary response Group which will return something like this:
...

```
["Items"]=> object(stdClass)#72 (2) { 
    ... 
    ["Item"]=> object(stdClass)#75 (2) {
        ["ASIN"]=> string(10) "1405910232" 
        ["OfferSummary"]=> object(stdClass)#76 (6) { 
            ["LowestNewPrice"]=> object(stdClass)#77 (3) {  
                ["Amount"]=> int(247) 
                ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "GBP" 
                ["FormattedPrice"]=> string(6) "£2.47" 
            } 
            ["LowestUsedPrice"]=> object(stdClass)#78 (3) {
                ["Amount"]=> int(297) 
                ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "GBP" 
                ["FormattedPrice"]=> string(6) "£2.97" 
            }
```

...

Answer (score 3):

Use "medium" for "ResponseGroup" parameter, allowed values small, medium and large. small response will not have the price details.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Small.html

Comment: The ResponseGroup=Small/Medium/Large all I tried but still it returns <ResponseGroup>Small</ResponseGroup> and no price details. Do you have any other thoughts about it?

Answer (score 2):

Xarem, please, take a look at [Product Advertising API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/DG/) (API Reference/Operations). You've requested ItemLookup operation and the price was not promissed for you. Use SellerListingLookup (or some other) operation to get available prices. This is quit understandable, because Amazon has a big pool of sellers and prices differ from one to another, so they can't provide prices for items, but for item-seller pairs.

Comment: Unfortunately, SellerListingLookup is not available anymore in (new) Product Advertising API.

Answer (score 2):

Had I enough rep I'd have commented on an earlier solution but alas I'm limited to providing a new answer...

So, if you pass a MerchantId value of All, you will see this in your response:

```
<MerchantId>Deprecated</MerchantId>
```

which indicates to me that perhaps you should not provide this parameter, counter to what the selected answer suggests.

More than that, I suspect there is something else going on.  I'll probably pose a whole new question about this here, but I am submitting a request for a product with a valid ASIN, getting back True, requesting the response groups Offers, OfferFull, and OfferSummary, and I am not getting back any price information.  Yet when I look at the very same product on amazom.com, I see see price information.

So something else could be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parser from [associate script](http://associatescript.cenware.com) to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your response group like as below:
responseGroup('Medium,OfferSummary,VariationSummary')

In response group you will get the key "VariationSummary" and inside this object you can check below params for price :

- LowestPrice
- HighestPrice
- LowestSalePrice
- HighestSalePrice

Note that you may not get all above 4 params in VariationSummary object.