# Php - Get Current Price of amazon products using Amazon API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I've successfully implemented amazon product search using the code given in:

[I don't get prices with Amazon Product Advertising API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304757/i-dont-get-prices-with-amazon-product-advertising-api).

Now I'm trying to fetch the current price of a product from Amazon. I got only the retail price.

For example, when I try to fetch the prices of the product: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0743273567/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0743273567) using amazon API, I got the following values:

```
ListPrice] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Amount] => 1500
                                [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                [FormattedPrice] => $15.00
                            )

                    )
....

[OfferSummary] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [LowestNewPrice] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Amount] => 343
                                [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                [FormattedPrice] => $3.43
                            )

                    )

                [LowestUsedPrice] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Amount] => 250
                                [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                [FormattedPrice] => $2.50
                            )

                    )

                [LowestCollectiblePrice] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Amount] => 995
                                [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                [FormattedPrice] => $9.95
                            )

                    )
.....

[OfferListing] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [OfferListingId] => nmbRKFxxDoRqoOL8kMzXNMkb9X2XWMB44HkNuwC49%2F8Yfcc96dCsb3rHWjDaIQT9fWHO%2BUGNIXWaBug5raFqChfsnCsdiGqPu4F7x0PZSPByUJd5zQ%2BM0%2FuuINUX917HJRDhHGwa9HTfCSlqfJlAB5V62ZgCa%2FmY
                                                [Price] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Amount] => 343
                                                                [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                                                [FormattedPrice] => $3.43
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [AmountSaved] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Amount] => 1157
                                                                [CurrencyCode] => USD
                                                                [FormattedPrice] => $11.57
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [PercentageSaved] => 77 .....
```

The retail price : **$15.00** can be seen in the ListPrice parameter, but I couldn't find the current price : **$7.70** anywhere in the api response.

I've also tried the various ResponseGroups like: Offers, OfferFull, Large, Medium etc.

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit late but to get the current price , you need to include Offers Responsegroup , and then get the current price from this node

```
$price = htmlentities((string) $item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Price->Amount);
```

as the XML actually looks like this

```
<Item> 
  <ASIN>B00KOKTZLQ</ASIN> 
  <OfferSummary> 
    <LowestNewPrice> 
      <Amount>3998</Amount> 
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode> 
      <FormattedPrice>$39.98</FormattedPrice> 
    </LowestNewPrice>  
    <TotalNew>4</TotalNew> 
    <TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed> 
    <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible> 
    <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished> 
  </OfferSummary> 
  <Offers> 
    <TotalOffers>1</TotalOffers> 
    <TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages> 
    <MoreOffersUrl>
    https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00KOKTZLQ/?&AWSAccessKeyId=[Your_AWSAccessKeyID]&ie=UTF8&tag=[Your_AssociateTag]%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00KOKTZLQ
    </MoreOffersUrl> 
    <Offer> 
      <OfferAttributes> 
        <Condition>New</Condition> 
      </OfferAttributes> 
      <OfferListing> 
        <OfferListingId>  
         LYcccWDl3oNWXKkngMuydLjjKXsOR4AO2tGTdMW%2BNOA%2F%2FV61ektF%2FstkahL39vySB75wmcQJ7lsWOW3NAjVZpwgnQnxZE62sf%2B34NWSBuAzkkR7lCjtGLXn0aFfQ5KAGmNFYzScqWHSecKmnMA%2BuBA%3D%3D 
        </OfferListingId> 
        <Price>  
          <Amount>6000</Amount>  
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>  
          <FormattedPrice>$60.00</FormattedPrice> 
        </Price> 
        <SalePrice>
            <Amount>4495</Amount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <FormattedPrice>$44.95</FormattedPrice>
        </SalePrice>
        <AmountSaved>
            <Amount>1505</Amount>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <FormattedPrice>$15.05</FormattedPrice>
        </AmountSaved>
        <PercentageSaved>25</PercentageSaved>
        <Availability>Usually ships in 1-2 business days</Availability> 
        <AvailabilityAttributes>  
          <AvailabilityType>now</AvailabilityType>  
          <MinimumHours>24</MinimumHours>  
          <MaximumHours>48</MaximumHours> 
        </AvailabilityAttributes> 
        <IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>0</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>
        <IsEligibleForPrime>0</IsEligibleForPrime>
      </OfferListing> 
    </Offer> 
  </Offers>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [amazon docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingPriceInformation.html), it suggests that `Operation=ItemLookup` return the product data and from that response you have `<LowestNewPrice><Amount>` tag which gives you latest price of requested item. So please refer that document provided by amazon.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already got 'LowestNewPrice' as '$3.43' (please check the xml provided in the question). Is there any way to get the current price as $7.70?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It'd also help us tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the price with response group like :
responseGroup('Medium,OfferSummary,VariationSummary')

The key : VariationSummary has the object where you can find:

- LowestPrice
- HighestPrice
- LowestSalePrice
- HighestSalePrice

Note that you may not get all above price params in variationSummery object so make the check accordingly.